# Userscript, get data with ajax and get content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm doing a userscript for a website. Some of its articles contains images and when you click them it opens in another page which i found boring and time wasting so i decided to make a userscript which instead of opening the image in another page will open in on the same page but in a popup like on most websites today. I'm using Magnific Popup for this. This is my code so far.

```
var link = '';
var link2 = '';

$("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" href = "https://49535f300cc62ae84be0bc4341ad834057099639.googledrive.com/host/0B7xSofmydrHqMU9pRDJXTEtpQWc">');

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('section[class="article"]').find("#intelliTXT").find('a').each(function(){ 

         link2 =  "http://www.gamergen.com"+ $(this).attr('href');
         $.ajax({
             url: link2,
             success: function (data){link = $(data).find('.big').find('img').attr('src');},
             error : function(){alert(link2)}
         });
         $(this).magnificPopup({
              items: {
                  src: link
              },
             type: 'image',
             closeOnContentClick: true,
             mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
             image: {
                 verticalFit: true
             }
         });   
     });
 });
```

The popup part is working and it opens an image in a popup when i click on it instead of following the link. The problem is that the actual link isn't the image itself but a webpage we are redirected to where the image is.

This: /image/mort-satoru-iwata-images-captures-splatoon-memorial-condoleance-5-811402-264278 is the link of the image on the main page and when we click on it we are redirected to another webpage where we can find the actual url of the image : http://global-img.gamergen.com/mort-satoru-iwata-images-captures-splatoon-memorial-condoleance-5_028001C600811402.jpg (everything is on the same domain and the image is situated on a subdomain. altough i don't access it with the ajax i just want to copy that link and past it on the main page in my popup)

Here's the html of that:

```
<a href="/image/mort-satoru-iwata-images-captures-splatoon-memorial-condoleance-11-811408-264278" title="Mort Satoru Iwata images captures splatoon memorial condoleance (11)" class="zoomLink"><img src="http://global-img.gamergen.com/mort-satoru-iwata-images-captures-splatoon-memorial-condoleance-11_00CE009200811408.jpg" alt="Mort Satoru Iwata images captures splatoon memorial condoleance (11)" width="206" height="146"></a>
```

(the image in  is a thumbnail)

So i tried using Ajax for that and and get the url from the webpage where the proper url of the image is located.

Just there's a problem with my ajax query, it always goes to the error function. So i've tried to make an alert to check if the url is the good one. And i got two problems, my url is always the same, and the second one is that the url is the good one but it doesn't enter success function anyway.

I'm kinda new to javascript. Shouldn't .each do every  element since i do .find('a').each ? And what's wrong with my ajax query?

Thank you

Comment: About the ajax, ajax usage is limited to current domain only. You cant do requests from `abc.com` to `def.com` (unless CORS is enabled).

Comment: @EntityBlack with userscript you can run your script on more than one domain which bypass CORS + it's the same domain anyway

Comment: that might be true. Then what error does your ajax returns? Or what is written in network in firebug/dev console?

Comment: @EntityBlack How can i check what's the error? I only did an alert to check what's the url and the url is good it just goes to the error function no matter what

Comment: modify error function in your ajax: 
`$.ajax({
    ...   
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(request);
        console.log(error);
    },
    ...
});`
then read message from console and try to figure out whats wrong our put it in your question